# Phonegap https-app: release version can't send data, debug version can

Tags: android, cordova, debugging, https, release

can anyone help me with the following question please:

My Android-App is able to send the data via `https` when compiling the `debug-version`, but the `release version` fails there.

The `https` certificate is not self-signed and the whitelist plugin is working.

Interesting is, that if the debug version is installed and then the `release version` is installed without deinstalling the `debug-version`, everything works out well.

Can anyone help me here? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solution:

The SSL-Chain was the problem for me.

1) To check if this might be an issue for your app, too, you may go to:
https://www.digicert.com/help/

Type in your domain (if already available online) and test your SSL-Configuration. If the last point does not say "SSL Certificate is correctly installed" and you bought your certificate from a trustworthy authority, this website already hints you at an issue you might have with the intermediate certificates.

2) Fix issue:
a) The intermediate certificates neccessary came with that SSL.rar-file you've once gotten. With the provider I had chosen, they sent me three .pem files (besides of other files of course) named:
01_COMODO_RSA_Organization_Validation_Secure_Server_CA, 02_COMODO_RSA_Certification_Authority, 
03_AddTrust_External_CA_Root
Other authorities might send you something like someName.ca-bundle. That's the same thing, as far as I understood it, and so can skip this a) part.

Concatenate the plain text of these three files, meaning store them in another file - altogether. No additional text changes neccessary. When storing this file, make sure it has the .crt file ending.

b) Upload your chosenName.crt to your server into the same folder your ssl.crt is stored in already.

c) Make this new file known within the system. In your .config file (e.g. default-ssl.conf), the same file you once added the paths to your "ssl".crt and .key in, set "SSLCertificateChainFile" to - example path: "/etc/ssl/ssl.crt/chosenName.crt" - and update the certficates (I used the command update-ca-certificates, but I'm not sure if this was neccessary at all.)

d) Stop and start your webserver. If an error message regarding wrong configuration is displayed, you have probably misstyped the path to the file or it's name and so it cannot be found. If your webserver starts successfully, you're done.

Another check on the link above (I am not allowed to have more than 2 links within this post) should now show you the SSL-Chain (containing now 4 instead of 1 certificate_s) and the above mentioned "SSL successfully installed" message should appear.

Hopefully this will help you!

Further info: 
Whether you need this SSL-Chain with 4 certificates or not is probably something that can vary. I looked it up on the comodo-support site because that was the SSL-certificate authority I had to deal with:
https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Default/Knowledgebase/Article/View/620/0/which-is-root-which-is-intermediate